# XML file attached to an email contains wrong characters

Tags: xml, vb.net, mimekit

I am downloading an email with a file "file.xml" attached to it.

When I save the file, the file is incorrectly saved with "=" replaced with "3D=".

Below is the example:

```
<?xml version=3D"1.0" encoding=3D"UTF-8"?><ns3:RicevutaConsegna xmlns:ns3=
    =3D"http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fattura/messaggi/v1.0"=
         xmlns:ns2=3D"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" versione=3D"1.0">
```

*instead* of:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns3:RicevutaConsegna xmlns:ns3=
"http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fattura/messaggi/v1.0"
xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" versione="1.0">
```

If I save the file with Thunderbird it works fine..

```
    client.CheckCertificateRevocation = False
    client.Connect("imap.pec.it", 993, True)

    client.Authenticate("xxxxxx@pec.it", "xxxx")
    client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly)
    Dim query = Search.SearchQuery.SubjectContains("Ricevuta di consegna")

    For Each uid In client.Inbox.Search(query)
        Dim messaggio = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(messaggio.Subject)

        For Each BodyPart In messaggio.BodyParts

            If BodyPart.ContentDisposition.FileName = "postacert.eml" Then
                Dim postacert As MimeKit.MessagePart = BodyPart

                TextBox1.Text = postacert.Message.Attachments(0).ToString
                Dim attach As MimeKit.MimePart = postacert.Message.Attachments(0)
                Dim file As FileStream = New FileStream(attach.FileName, FileMode.Create)
                attach.Content.WriteTo(b.FileName)
                file.Close()
```

Is there an error?

(I am working in VB.NET.)

Answer (score 1):

Find the mismach..
i use :

```
attach.Content.WriteTo(file)
```

*instead* of:

```
attach.Content.DecodeTo(file)
```